# Find total combinations for array of object values

Tags: javascript

I need a function that takes this array of objects, `input`, and creates all the different possible combinations it can have that add up to 100 for its values, as demonstrated partially in the expected `output`. Note that `secondaryType` needs to be taken into account too, as per output.

I've been wracking my brains on how to do this but can't find the answer myself. Help is greatly appreciated.

```
const input = [
  {
    type: 'A',
    value: 10,
    secondaryType: 'X'
  },
  {
    type: 'B',
    value: 20,
    secondaryType: 'Y'
  },
  {
    type: 'C',
    value: 20,
    secondaryType: 'Z'
  },
  {
    type: 'D',
    value: 20
  },
  {
    type: 'E',
    value: 30
  }
]
```

Output:

```
[
  {A: 10, B: 20, C: 20, D: 20, E: 30},
  {X: 10, B: 20, C: 20, D: 20, E: 30},
  {X: 10, Y: 20, C: 20, D: 20, E: 30},
  etc...
];
```

Comment: Where is the function you've tried that didn't work?

Comment: This would be easier (imo) if the types were in an array `types: ['A', 'X']` etc..., rather than being separate properties on your object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the types, build a cartesian product and map the objects with their values from `input`.

```js
const
    input = [{ type: 'A', value: 10, secondaryType: 'X' }, { type: 'B', value: 20, secondaryType: 'Y' }, { type: 'C', value: 20, secondaryType: 'Z' }, { type: 'D', value: 20 }, { type: 'E', value: 30 }],
    result = input
        .map(({ type, secondaryType }) => secondaryType === undefined ? [type] : [type, secondaryType] )
        .reduce((a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))), []))
        .map(a => Object.fromEntries(a.map((k, i) => [k, input[i].value])));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Liked the css modification to show the console "full screen". I wonder thought, 5 letter combination without repeating is 5! (120), not 8.

Comment: @MoshFeu, it is `2 * 2 * 2 * 1 * 1`. each one or two properties per object.